# Insert the row to the Queryset manually

Tags: python, django

I have objects and filter, which get the `label` `value` pair from database.

```
    results = (m.Drawing.objects.
    annotate(label=F('update_user__name'),value=F('update_user')).
    values('label','value').
    annotate(dcount=Count('update_user__name')).
    order_by())
    
    print(results)

    serializer = s.SearchChoiceSerializer(instance=results, many=True)
```

Results is like this,`print(results)`

```
<SafeDeleteQueryset [{'label': 'admin', 'value': 1, 'dcount': 13}, {'label': 'demouser1', 'value': 2, 'dcount': 13}]>
```

Now, I want to insert this `{'label':'myuser', 'value':2,'dcount':23}`  to `SafeDeleteQuerySet` manually before sending to the serializer.

I it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn your queryset into a list, modify it, and send it then to the serializer:

```
objs = list(results)
objs.append({'label':'myuser', 'value':2,'dcount':23})

serializer = s.SearchChoiceSerializer(instance=objs, many=True)
```

*Assuming your serializer can handle lists.*

Comment: Thank you I wondered how to change to list, but it's quite simple.